# Android app can't find libraries in production

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react-native project that is using external .aar libraries. The project works fine in development (and when I run **build apk**), but when I **generate a signed apk** and try and run it in production, the app can no longer find it’s libraries.

Using ADB, the logs that are shown when trying to access the libraries in a live environment are:

```
W/System.err( 5536): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.pax.dal.impl.DALProxy" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/resource/public/PaxDALImpl.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/resource/public, /data/resource/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
W/System.err( 5536):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
W/System.err( 5536):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
W/System.err( 5536):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
W/System.err( 5536):    at com.e.c.a.a.b.b(Utils.java:113)
W/System.err( 5536):    at com.e.c.a.a.a.a(NeptuneDiamondUser.java:38)
W/System.err( 5536):    at com.e.e.g.b.b(POSLinkPrinter.java:215)
W/System.err( 5536):    at com.e.e.g.b.a(POSLinkPrinter.java:203)
W/System.err( 5536):    at com.e.e.g.b$2.run(POSLinkPrinter.java:127)
W/System.err( 5536):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err( 5536):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err( 5536):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err( 5536):    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/pax/dal/proxy/IDALProxy;
W/System.err( 5536):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 5536):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
W/System.err( 5536):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
W/System.err( 5536):        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
W/System.err( 5536):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
W/System.err( 5536):        ... 10 more
```

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: do u get any error ?

Comment: Add proguard rules for each aar or disable progaurd in production build(not advised)

Comment: @Nima I've edited my post with the relevant ADB logs

Comment: I managed to solve this by setting minify=false in my build.gradle. Must be an issue referencing certain libraries between react-native and android when the code is minified.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by setting minify=false in my build.gradle. Must be an issue referencing certain libraries between react-native and android when the code is minified.